# How to scale up apps in XCode for diffrent screen sizes

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm working on an app for iPad but when I set the contrains(so it works on iPad Pro/iPad Mini) everything moved.
 I don't know if I set anything wrong or if it's problems with XCode However, are there a way to just like scale up/down the screen without contrains?
 Or how to fix the constrains problem.
(I choose all buttons and click add missing constrains)

Picture:
[image]

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking for, maybe you just set the constraints wrong, you should show us a screen and give details about your storyboard?

Comment: I select all and click add missing constrains and the picture is the link.(I can't put up the image because I don't have enough reputation)

Comment: Are you making this app through storyboard or code?

Comment: Add missing constraints automatically is not an ultimate solution. Xcode could add something which does not make sense in your case. You probably need to go and add all needed constraints manually.

Comment: Just "Add missing constraints" does not guarantee to keep the proportions, i am sorry but in my opinion the question is a bit too broad to be answered here, maybe read a bit more about how do constraints work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO selecting *add missing constraints* is not exactly what you want. If you want your view to scale up when screen is larger, you need to set the constraints to its superview. So you just say *I want it to be 10 pt from the leading edge and 15 pt from the trailing edge*. By adding missing constraints Xcode probably tells the view to be *xy* points wide.

To set the constraints as I mentioned you need to Ctrl drag from the view to its superview and add leading constraint. Similarly for the trailing and eventually top and bottom constraints.